# What does "sex idiot" mean?

Tags: meaning

In this video clip from [30 Rock](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=TsDiEq2R_c8), the woman says

> Ryan is *my* sex idiot.

I wonder what it means?

Is it a general usage to add an adjective to "idiot" to give it some special meaning?

Comment: Please provide a transcription of the relevant bits with sufficient context.

Comment: I added the transcribed sentence, but there isn't much context.  It sounds like there must have been a reference to "sex idiots" earlier in the show.

Comment: @KitFox: Is it a general phrase?

Comment: @Tim I don't know.

Comment: The video clip is a teaser, so no idea @KitFox if there is a definition elsewhere in the show – yet. [Elsewhere](http://www.awfulannouncing.com/2012-articles/september/ryan-lochte-will-play-sex-idiot-on-30-rock.html) we also have: "[Lochte] played … a sex idiot. He was good at it." My impression is the phrase should simply be taken literally: a person who is an idiot when it comes to sex.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear when discussing English/what exists in the English language, I would take anything having to do with Ryan Lochte with a grain of salt.

He's known to be an "idiot" in general, and I think here it may mean something along the lines of, all he's worth to her is sex.  Good looking, athletic, but when it comes to the smarts, he's just plain stupid.

So maybe they just have sex, without anything else. Because... he's an idiot.

Hope that helps, haven't seen this show.